# Trying to figure out how to go around Promise: Pending situation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I could not find a proper way to get my GET handler working. In the code below, when I send a GET request to that endpoint, my array element are all showing as 'Promise: Pending'. Can you suggest a way to go around it? I tried using setTimeout() method but I feel like it is not a proper solution.

Thank you in advance.

```
apiRouter.get('/photos', (req,res,next) => {
    axios.get("https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption&access_token={some_access_token}")
    .then(response => {
        const photosArr = response.data.data;
        const arr = photosArr.map(id => {
            return axios.get(`https://graph.instagram.com/${id.id}?fields=id,media_type,media_url,username,timestamp&access_token={some_acces_token}`)
            .then(response => {
                 return response.data.media_url;
            })
        })
        res.send(arr);
        next();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a useful case to use `async` / `await`

The problem is that you are returning the promise in your `Array.map()`. Even though you have a `.then` block after your promise, the promise itself is what is being returned because this is running asynchronously.

Something like this should be close

```
apiRouter.get('/photos', async (req,res,next) => {
    const response = await axios.get("https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption&access_token={some_access_token}")
    const photosArr = response.data.data;
    const arr = photosArr.map(async (id) => {
        const resp await axios.get(`https://graph.instagram.com/${id.id}?fields=id,media_type,media_url,username,timestamp&access_token={some_acces_token}`)
         return resp.data.media_url;
    };
    const final = await Promise.all(arr);
    res.send(final);
    next();
})
```

Comment: Async functions return promises. So, after mapping over `photosArr`, wouldn't you still have an array of unresolved promises that you're sending back with your solution?

Comment: Good catch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all promises in an array to resolve:

````
apiRouter.get('/photos', (req,res,next) => {
    axios.get("https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption&access_token={some_access_token}")
    .then(response => {
        const photosArr = response.data.data;
        Promise.all(photosArr.map(id => {
            return axios.get(`https://graph.instagram.com/${id.id}?fields=id,media_type,media_url,username,timestamp&access_token={some_acces_token}`)
            .then(response => {
                 return response.data.media_url;
            })
        })).then(photos => {
          res.send(photos);
          next();
        })
    })
})```
````